# Need to compare two excel columns and then return value from third colume

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
Date             Number        Width
------           -------       ------
21/10/20         NS001         35
22/10/20         NS005         38


Date.            Number        Width
------           -------       -----
19/10/20         NS004         -
22/10/20         NS005         38 (need to find this value)
```

As illustrated above, I need to find the Width in the second table where the Date and Number column match. I have tried using INDEX and MATCH but not able to compare two columns. Below is the formula I am using. (Both tables are in different tabs in one Excel file)

=INDEX(TABLE 1-WIDTH,MATCH(TABLE2-NUMBER, TABLE1-NUMBER,0))

I need to match the date column as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. Remember to use control + shift + enter instead of enter.

`=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(F3&G3,A:A&B:B,0))`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer @HoodedOne, how about if the rows get updated from time to time so instead of lets C2:C3, is it possible to use $C:$C instead?

Comment: I edited it so you can use with the whole column.